Communicate between a Python Server and C++ Client
The C++ client connects to the Python server without any issues, but when I send a message it's never received by the server.
I don't get any errors or unexpected results on the client either, it sends the message without any problems, but the server never reacts to it so something is going wrong in between.
Here's the full C++ client code:
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include "iostream"
#include <tchar.h>
#define IP "127.0.0.1"
constexpr int PORT = 3000;
int main() {
    std::cout << "======== CC Client ========" << std::endl;

    std::cout << "==== Invoke WSAStartup ====" << std::endl;
    SOCKET clientSocket;
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int wsaerr;
    WORD wVersionRequested = MAKEWORD(2, 2);
    wsaerr = WSAStartup(wVersionRequested, &wsaData);
    if (wsaerr == 0) {
        std::cout << "Winsock dll found!" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Status: " << wsaData.szSystemStatus << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Winsock dll not found." << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    std::cout << "===== Creating Socket =====" << std::endl;
    clientSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (clientSocket != INVALID_SOCKET) 
        std::cout << "socket() is OK!" << std::endl;
    else {
        std::cout << "Error at socket():" << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
        WSACleanup();
        return 0;
    }
    
    std::cout << "==== Connect to Server ====" << std::endl;
    sockaddr_in clientService;
    clientService.sin_family = AF_INET;
    InetPton(AF_INET,_T(IP), &clientService.sin_addr.s_addr);
    clientService.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    if (connect(clientSocket, (SOCKADDR*)&clientService, sizeof(clientService)) != SOCKET_ERROR) {
        std::cout << "Client: connect() is OK." << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Connected to: " << IP << ":" << PORT << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Client: Can start sending and receiving data..." << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Client: connect() - Failed to connect." << std::endl;
        WSACleanup();
        return 0;
    }

    std::cout << "== Communicate to Server ==" << std::endl;
    
    char buffer[200];
    std::cout << "Enter a message:" << std::endl;
    std::cin.getline(buffer, 200);
    int byteCount = send(clientSocket, buffer, 200, 0);
    if (byteCount > 0)
        std::cout << "Message sent: " << buffer << std::endl;
    else {
        std::cout << "Message failed to send." << std::endl;
        WSACleanup();
    }

    std::cout << "===== Clean up Socket =====" << std::endl;
    system("pause");
    WSACleanup();
}

And here's the full Python server code:
import asyncio
import websockets


async def handler(websocket):
    while True:
        try:
            message = await websocket.recv()
            print(message)
        except websockets.ConnectionClosedOK:
            break
        except websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosed:
            print("A client suddenly disconnected.")


async def main():
    async with websockets.serve(handler, "localhost", 3000):
        await asyncio.Future()  # run forever

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())


I don't understand where the problem is, because both sides work individually (I can communicate with the python server through the console command python -m websockets ws://localhost:8001/), so I don't see any reason why they wouldn't be able to communicate.
My guess is that something is wrong on the C++ side but I followed a tutorial and I can't find any discrepancies from what was done in that video.

Web sockets have a protocol that you don't seem to be implementing in the C++ code. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_servers

The python side is getting the raw plaintext the user typed in. It is not getting any of the HTTP headers it expects, so it's discarding the input as non-conforming garbage.

@Valdez The tutorial used the clientSocket and it works for them. I could try to change to UDP and see if that works, will be back with the results in a bit. Does the firewall still block the connection if both the server and client are running on the same PC? They won't later but during testing they are, and I was under the impression that the firewall doesn't care in that case.

@user4581301 Aha, that sounds sensible. How can I change it so either the client send the correct format or the server stops caring about the format?

If you can get the initial TCP handshaking through a firewall, you're dealing with an unusual firewall configuration if the rest is discarded.

"the client send the correct format" Read the RFC, implement what it says. Alternativelym just use an off-the-shelf third party websocket library. "or the server stops caring about the format" Don't use websockets, use regular TCP sockets.

For something simple like this you could hard-code the HTTP headers on the C++ side. Example. If you want to do HTTP right, you'll want to use a library because there are too many boobytraps involved for a rookie to write it all by hand in a reasonable amount of time. Hell of a learning experience, though. cURL and Boost::beast are common go-to libraries.

@user4581301 I copied the example you gave me, but it still doesn't seem to work. I'll try one of the libraries you suggested next.

@massacring Is there a reason you need to use web sockets? There is an initial handshake using the headers, but the data is also encoded. It's not impossible to do these things, but simpler to use regular sockets.

@001 Yeah, my ultimate goal is to communicate to a mod for minecraft called CC: Tweaked. The computers added by that mod can only communicate outside the game through websockets. I chose to do so through C++ and am sticking to it mostly because I'm stubborn x). The python server I'm using currently is just for testing.

If you can use third party C++ libraries then you might want to look at boost.beast.

@G.M. welp too late already looking into cURL xD I assume it doesn't matter too much which one I use.

When you have the time, play with a few different libraries. You'll find the one you like best.
